# Retaining a value in an R dataset if it's present in another dataset

Tags: r, vector, subset

I am currently working on a code which applies to various datasets from an experiment which looks at a wide range of variables which might not be present in every repetition. My first step is to create an empty dataset with all the possible variables, and then write a function which retains columns that are in the dataset being inputted and delete the rest. Here is an example of how I want to achieve this:-

```
x<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
y<-c("c","f","g")
```

Is there a way of removing elements of x that aren't present in y and/or retaining values of x that are present in y?

Comment: Perhaps `intersect(x,y)` or check `setdiff`

Answer (score 1):

For your first question: "My first step is to create an empty dataset with all the possible variables", I would use `factor` on the concatenation of all the vectors, for example:

```
all_vect = c(x, y)
possible = levels(factor(all_vect))
```

Then, for the second part " write a function which retains columns that are in the dataset being inputted and delete the rest", I would write:

```
df[,names(df)%in%possible]
```

Comment: This answer is not helpful in any way. If you only want unique values, just use `unique`

Answer (score 0):

As akrun wrote, use intersect(x,y) or

```
> x[x %in% y]
```

Comment: This is basically the source code of `intersect`. Type `intersect` in console